# I have dialogflow bot integrated with skype, but I cannot find the bot in my company's skype application

Tags: azure, botframework, dialogflow-es, skype

I have built a bot using dialogflow and integrated with skype as its channel.

Now I can test the bot in https://dev.botframework.com and it is working properly. But I cannot figure out how to connect with it in my company's skype application.

The documentation is not very clear and it might be just that I am missing a few steps.Any help would be useful.

[image]

Comment: When you say « my company’s Skype application », you are in fact talking about Skype for Business?

Comment: yes.. it is skype for business. But is that not depreciated?

Comment: It will not be supported after end of June... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-bot-framework/docs/overview

Comment: Then what should be the way to connect my bot to my org's skype account?

Comment: Honestly... I don't know, as Microsoft is pushing towards Teams instead of SfB. My company switched a couple months ago

Comment: I had a similar problem with a hangouts bot because I didn't know how to talk to *any* bot.  Perhaps you have the same problem?  If so, https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34646/what-are-skype-bots-and-how-do-i-add-them-as-contacts describes what to do.